# Mongoose how to update an user info

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having trouble making the @PUT method for my application. So far, I managed to make the @GET, @POST and @DELETE. So after doing some research, it turns out that the @PUT is a mixture of my @GET and @POST.

*My @GET (by cuid) method*

```
export function getUser(req, res) {
  // just get the user information
  User.findOne({ cuid: req.params.cuid }).exec((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    return res.json({ user });
  });
}
```

*My @POST method*

```
export function addUser(req, res) {
  // Check for empty fields
  if (!req.body.user.firstName || !req.body.user.lastName ||    
          !req.body.user.email || !req.body.user.password ||
          !req.body.user.studentId) {
     return res.status(403).end();
 }

  const newUser = new User(req.body.user);

  // Let's sanitize inputs
  newUser.firstName = sanitizeHtml(newUser.firstName);
  newUser.lastName = sanitizeHtml(newUser.lastName);
  newUser.studentId = sanitizeHtml(newUser.studentId);
  newUser.email = sanitizeHtml(newUser.email);
  newUser.password = sha512(newUser.password).toString('hex');

  newUser.cuid = cuid();
  newUser.save((err, saved) => {
  if (err) {
     return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
    return res.json({ user: saved });
  });
}
```

The `req.body.user` will be the same in the @PUT method as in the addUser function on the @POST. In other words, the `req.body.user` will be something like `{ firstname: 'assa', lastName: 'nen', email: 'ed@aid.com', password: 'ddee', student: 112 }`

**My question is** how would you modify the specific user (by cuid) information and save it to the db? In other words, how would you write the @PUT method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)

```
export function updateUser(req, res) {

 var userId = req.body.userId;

 var conditions = {
  _id : userId 
 }

 var update = {
  firstName = sanitizeHtml(req.body.firstName );
  lastName = sanitizeHtml(req.body.lastName);
  studentId = sanitizeHtml(req.body.studentId);
  email = sanitizeHtml(req.body.email);
  password = sha512(req.body.password).toString('hex');
 }

  model.findOneAndUpdate(conditions,update,function(error,result){
    if(error){
      // handle error
    }else{
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Important to note that this approach will not execute the model validation in the mongoose schema unless you also pass the runValidators: true option.